# Angular: How to fix SameSite Cookie issue

Tags: angular, cookies, header, http-headers, setcookie

My application is on **dev-server**. It is working in all platforms except Facebook app browser in mobile, although its working on chrome mobile browser.

I wasted so many hours and after that I discovered this warning regarding `SameSite Cookie`:
[image]

I've read instructions from https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/

My project is running by `Angular`. I don't know whether I have to set the `set-cookie` as ideal Cookie or in Request/Response header.

I've already tried as Request Header like https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers. And I don't have idea how to `set-cookie` in Response Header.

I also don't know any other alternatives.